# Links not clickable, only long-pressable on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I've got a strange bug in a Wordpress site that I've taken over (I didn't develop it, and the code is a bit of a mess in places).

The mobile nav works fine if I resize my desktop browser, but if I go to it on my iPhone, the links aren't clickable. The ARE long-pressable (I can open in a new tab, for instance), but tapping on them does nothing on my iPhone, in both Safari and Chrome.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

My staging server where I'm working is here: frame.staging.wpengine (though it's also broken on the main site, and has been for I don't know how long).

The HTML (when inspected) is:

```
<div id="mobile-nav" style="display: block;">

    <div id="mobile-nav-button0" style="transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20.0001, 0, 0, 1);">
        <a href="https://blog.frame.io/">BLOG HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div id="mobile-nav-button1" style="transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20.0001, 0, 0, 1);">
        <a href="https://blog.frame.io/2017/02/09/manifesto">MANIFESTO</a>
    </div> 
    <div id="mobile-nav-button2" style="transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 20.0001, 0, 0, 1);">
        <a href="#footer-email-wrapper">SUBSCRIBE</a>
    </div>
    <div id="mobile-nav-button3" style="transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 19.9992, 0, 0, 1);">
        <a href="https://frame.io/">VIDEO REVIEW TOOLS</
    </div>

</div>
```

The style="transform..." is added by javascript when I open the mobile nav.

Here are the css rules applied to #mobile-nav.

```
#mobile-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: AzoWeb-Bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2e323f;
}
```

There's a js file for the menu "hamburger-menu.js", but it's 1600 lines :/
If there's nothing that can be identified without digging through all of that javascript, I think I might have to just trash it and build my own (simpler) mobile nav bar.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of html code of a link that has this issue? Also the css associated with the link would be a great thing to add to help us troubleshoot.

Comment: I added the relevant HTML and CSS - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to you're [site](http://frame.staging.wpengine) in mobile view. Every time I click the link. This warning appears in the console:

`Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080`

What seems to be happening is that you have some jquery that is stopping the anchor tag from navigating. Only for mobile. I tried to trace through your JS but it's minified.

Hope that helps you debug. Cheers.